# Getting user photo url and profile url using views_json

Tags: 7, views

I'm using the views_json module in [Views Datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource) to send some information in JSON format to a related website.  I've got a bunch of content views built, but now I'm trying to build staff pages.  I've got most of it working fine, but when I try to add the user picture I end up with an empty field, When trying to find a url for the user's profile page (using User: Link), I got the text "view", leading me to believe that when drupal tries to output the content as a link, views_json returns the link text.  I just want the url in plaintext, I don't need the html for a link.  How can I get the user picture, and the absolute url to the user profile in views_json?

Image fields for my node views work just fine, I get field_image.src and field_image.alt elements in the JSON that is returned, with the Use picture I get a blank field or a series of `\n`´s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: There was a [follow up comment on the drupal.org thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/2396813#comment-11571515) where someone suggested using [Views User Picture URL](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_upu).  Since the solution below already works for me I haven't tried it, but this solution seems easier and reasonable. **/UPDATE**

@no-sssweat provided a superb answer, but it turned out that my problem was the result of a [bug in views_datasource](https://www.drupal.org/node/2396813) in that thread, @tyler-frankenstein [provides a really useful solution](https://www.drupal.org/node/2396813#comment-10461959).  Based on that I was able to get both the url path and profile link issues resolved:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_views_json_style_simple().
 * solution for user pictures not showing up properly in views_json
 * via https://www.drupal.org/node/2396813#comment-10461959
 */
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_views_views_json_style_simple(&$vars) {
    $views_to_process = array(
        'user_view' => array(
            'uid_column_name' => 'uid',
            'picture_column_name' => 'picture',
            'image_style' => 'medium',
            'url_column_name' => 'url',
        ),
        'my_other_user_view' => array(
            'uid_column_name' => 'uid',
            'picture_column_name' => 'picture',
            'image_style' => 'medium',
            'url_column_name' => 'url',
        )
    );
    if (!in_array($vars['view']->name, array_keys($views_to_process))) { return; }
    $uids = array();
    $uid_column_name = $views_to_process[$vars['view']->name]['uid_column_name'];
    $picture_column_name = $views_to_process[$vars['view']->name]['picture_column_name'];
    $image_style = $views_to_process[$vars['view']->name]['image_style'];
    $url_column_name = $views_to_process[$vars['view']->name]['url_column_name'];
    foreach ($vars['rows'] as $i => $row) {
        $uid = $row[$uid_column_name];
        $uids[] = $uid;
    }
    $users = user_load_multiple($uids);
    foreach ($vars['rows'] as $i => $row) {
        $uid = $row[$uid_column_name];
        $vars['rows'][$i][$url_column_name] = url(drupal_get_path_alias('user/' . $uid), array('absolute' => TRUE));
        if (!$users[$uid]->picture) { continue; }
        $vars['rows'][$i][$picture_column_name] = array(
            'src' => image_style_url($image_style, $users[$uid]->picture->uri)
        );
    }
}
```

replacing `user_view` and `my_other_user_view` with the names of views this needs to work on and putting the label names in the `uid_column_name`, `picture_column_name` and `url_column_name` as well as filling in the value for the image style you've chosen for your picture field will result in your picture and url fields being filled with data like so:

```
"url" : "http://link.to.the/users/profile",
"photo" : {
  "src" : "http://link.to.the/users/profile/picture/with/styles/applied/properly.jpg?itok=ipLMAws_"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the user pic url, you can do it using [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter). Once enabled, when you click on the user picture field, you will now see a formatter option, select image url.

For the user, assuming this is a user view, in FIELDS add the **User: Uid** as a field and checkmark ☑ exclude from display.

Now, add **Global: Custom text** as a field. In the text box, put `http://ultrabob.com/user/[uid]`

I got `[uid]` from replacement patterns. Side note, in order for fields to appear as a replacement pattern, they must be above the current field.

Else, if you're using [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) so the user pages are /user/[username] then add the **User: Name** field instead and use the `[name]` token.

Now, if your view is a content view, ex: shows articles, then you will need to add a relationship of node author first, once you do that, the user fields will become available to be added as a field.

---

> OK, that issue got me sorted with the pictures, I'm now working on the
>   solution for profile page link. Can you think of a good way to get the
>   domain part of the url (http://ultrabob.com/) in your example
>   dynamically in views from the site configuration. I would like this to
>   continue to work without modification as it is deployed across test
>   servers and onto production

You can using php. Ex: `<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>`

Either you could enable the Views PHP module, but remember to turn it off on production, or use a template file.

views-view-field--[view-name]--views-data-export--[field-name].tpl.php

```
<?php

$fields["field_name"]->content = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/user/' . $fields["field_name"]->content;

echo $fields["field_name"]->content;
```

Comment: hmmm, I've enabled the Image URL Formatter module, cleared cache and reloaded the view, but I'm still not seeing any formatter option.  I wonder what I'm missing.

Comment: I clicked back over to my node view and confirm I get the formatters on my node image field.  It seems not to work for user picture.  I found an [open issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2396813) which I'll go investigate.

Comment: This is a great answer and got me working toward the right answer for this particular situation.  In the end I managed to get it all solved in a `hook_preprocess_views_views_json_style_simple` call, so I'll put up an answer with that solution in it.  Thanks as always for your great help!

Comment: @UltraBob oh cool, didn't know about that hook.