# Rewrite results for user picture to except tokens

Tags: views, users, tokens, javascript

I have a user role called "Residents" in D7, and created a view the show profile information. I want to add colorbox to the User Picture, but there is only one token available [picture]. How do I add the image path as the destination if I can only use one token (see attachment)?

[image: The Rewrite option for this field only allows for one token to be used.]

Comment: If you haven't got live users on the site, now is the time to stop using user picture and add an image field to the user entity instead. Much easier to work with, and you can then install modules that work with image fields and have them work right away.

Comment: I believe there’s active users, but a high percentage of them don’t have profile pictures. So that may be a good solution. Thanks!

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at these two solutions:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2396813#comment-11571515

and

[Getting user photo url and profile url using views_json](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206731/getting-user-photo-url-and-profile-url-using-views-json)

Answer (score 0):

Generally I would advocate using an image field on the user entity over the legacy user picture feature. The latter has a lot of limitations and you have just discovered one of them. If you try solving this issue by in the theme layer you'll find in the template that all you have to work with is an opaque "picture" variable containing the image html plus the original account object, meaning that to do anything different you have to re-implement the logic that generated the image html yourself. Not very helpful.

By using a custom image field you have access to a whole raft of contrib modules that integrate with it - including colorbox - without the need for custom code.